# Select query for min-max scaling data over conditions (mysql)

Tags: mysql, select, scaling

I have measured and logged data from different sensors and different physical quantities in the same table.
I am trying to select those data with a min-max scaling normalization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) done over different subset based on physical quantities.
I tried different approaches: groups, partitions, subsets but I am certainly doing it wrong.
Yes, I managed to select min-max normalized data for a specific subset of measurements, but now I need to select many normalized subsets at once.

Comment: To be more clear, I need to select sensor values from different sensors in a range 0-1 where 0 and 1 are respectively is the min and the max values among that specific sensor measurements

Comment: Here is an answer to a very similar question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211117/mysql-feature-scaling-calculation